# Print out all code in a Python script

Tags: python, reflection

How can I print out the contents of a Python script?

For example, if I have this (pointless example) script:

```
my_var = 1 + 1
another_thing = "this is my string"
```

What line can I add to it, to get the entire contents back?

```
my_var = 1 + 1
another_thing = "this is my string"

# Magically print out all of the code in this file
print .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs that print out their source code are called quines. There are a few good examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223285/645956).

The easiest way is to read the script's source file:

```
print open(__file__).read()
```

If you can't read from the file, you'll need to wrap all your code in strings. You can then execute the strings and print them separately.