# Source Code is the output in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My friend gave me a challenge where the code is the same as the one in the output in python 3

I tried something like this :

```
input("")
```

Then you would type

> input("")

into the shell.... but I assume the question is asking for it without user interactions.
Thanks

Comment: This is a really vague and unhelpful question, can you provide some more details or an example.
Is the challenge to have the code print a string of the source code to the console?

Comment: I think you're describing a [*quine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)), which should help you find examples yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shortest python quine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223285/shortest-python-quine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you are talking about is a quine.

a Simple quine in python would be

```
s = r"print 's = r\"{0}\"'.format(s), '\n', s" 
print 's = r\"{0}\"'.format(s), '\n', s
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)).

In essence, a quine is a program which prints its own source code.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223285/shortest-python-quine) for some examples.