# Python quine without %r and %s

Tags: python-3.x, quine

I know of the shortest Python quine
([shortest python quine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223285/shortest-python-quine)) but it looks like a winner of a Python obfuscation challenge. It is cryptic.

Is there a Python quine that is easy to understand for a beginner: with variables, IFs, loops, but that doesnot rely on special exotic features of Python? The one that you don't "just memorize, consider it a password", but you can actually derive?

---

One can use any tools from a typical "Python. One hour crash course". Nope, %s and %r doesnot belong there. While `my_string.replace("foo","bar")` does.

Comment: Here's a slightly de-obfuscated version.  It still requires `!r` though: `magic = 'magic = {!r}; print(magic.format(magic))'; print(magic.format(magic))`

Comment: haha - those are just outdated - they used to be the only way to do string formatting! but sounds like fun. you might enjoy [codegolf.se]!

Comment: @0x5453 this is still some obfuscated stuff. Looks like a password, that I have to memorize. No, I've never used `!r` in the real life. Can it be written in a human readable code?

Comment: @michaelDelgano https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python+quine no relevant hits.

Answer (score 2):

This solution abuses how lists are printed

```
s = ["print('s =', s, ';', s[0])"] ; print('s =', s, ';', s[0])
```